# Where to find EmailAddressAttribute?

Tags: c#, windows-store

I'm developing an application under windows store 8.1 and I need to use email validation. I've figure it out that there is an `EmailAddressAttribute` in .Net Framework 4.5 in the namespace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.EmailAddressAttribute` However I can't find it there. I've included the `DataAnnotations` namespace but there is no `EmailAddressAttribute` there. could anyone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

According to the link you provided, it's in the assembly System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll in the namespace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`.  Did you add the reference?  Does the reference appear to have any problem in your project?

Comment: I'm working with windows store apps I can't include any assemblies. All the required assemblies are referenced by the VS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .net 4.5 (VS 2012) and want to valide using the EmailAddressAttribute. This is the way to use it:

```
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "...")]
```

With this, you remove the DataType (EmailAddress includes DataType functionality as it's derived from DataTypeAttribute) and the Regex.

For Validation Example:

```
[Display(Name = "Email address")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The email address is required")]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Krunal Patil but I don't think it works for validation.

Comment: It does work for me. I'm using 4.5 framework just the difference is I'm doing it in mvc4. But is it that you are trying to validate format of email address, than it may not

Comment: check my updated answer for Email address validation

Comment: Yes I'm trying  to validate the format of the email address. There suppose to be and built-in attribute to do the job here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.emailaddressattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx so where is it? I can't find anything like that.

Comment: Actually I've included that namespace but there is no EmailAddressAttribute there.

Comment: I got your point, but you are missing what I'm trying to tell you, check my edited answer, for your solution.

Comment: I absolutely did what you said in your edited answer but the VS says "the type or namespace name 'EmailAddress' could not be found. That's very strange.

Comment: than the issue seems to be with your reference dll.

Comment: You're right but since I'm working with windows store apps I can't include any assemblies. All the required assemblies are referenced by the VS.

Comment: Sorry but thats not my area of expertise.

Comment: Thanks anyway @Krunal Patil

Answer (score 0):

System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.EmailAddressAttribute is available starting .Net4.5.

Since I thought I was using 4.5 but was actually using 4.0 (-.-), I advise anyone reading this to recheck the Projects .Net Version. =)

(Rightclick "Projectname" in Solution Explorer -> Properties -> Tab "Application" -> "Target Framework")

@user3530012 pointed out that he/she is using .Net 4.5 so I guess this isn't the answer to this Question, but maybe it helps others.

Comment: Also I would like to point out, that it might not be the best way of validating the format. There are many SO pages about that, with even more regexes for this task. Here is one from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-verify-that-strings-are-in-valid-email-format